# mongodb - mongoimport stopOnError option

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, getlasterror

As per the mongodb documentation, stopOnError option forces mongoimport to halt the import operation at the first error rather than continuing the operation despite errors.

What are the various errors for which this option works?

I have tested it for the following error conditions:

1. Stopped the mongod instance. I get following error indicating it lost connection with the mongodb.

   ```
   assertion: 10276 DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 127.0.0.1:15055 ns: admin.$cmd query: { getlasterror: 1 }
   ```
2. Imported the same file again to same db and collection. This should give me duplicate entry error. Although, the error is displayed, import is not halted.

   ```
   Mon Jul 15 16:28:40.652 E11000 duplicate key error index: users.contacts_2.$_id_  dup key: { : "xexjiroiqcwujiuxrmedntmxhalniwygdyplrfvkjvfugdvxpadfvpferqtaquht" }
   Mon Jul 15 16:28:40.652 check 9 11
   Mon Jul 15 16:28:40.652 E11000 duplicate key error index: users.contacts_2.$_id_  dup key: { : "uyioegyqcenijjickljgdpmvihvyefvyfenjkmcptqafalhmwrvbjkwrtutybpxg" }
   Mon Jul 15 16:28:40.652 imported 10 objects
   ```

Now, i am confused. Does stopOnError works just for network errors or also for write error? Is there any way we can set write concerns or get the getLastError status while using mongoimport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stopOnError explicitly skips the duplicate key error as can be seen from the source at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/tools/import.cpp#L314. I have filed
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-1709 to have the documentation specify this.

Comment: Thank you Sridhar. Any idea about the different types of errors for which stopOnError works? I just want to be sure that if i use mongoimport instead of bulk insert, I will get the write commit ack as clear as getLastError.

Comment: Oh, mongo import code does call getLastError after every insert. Thankyou.